# convertir filas a columnas en sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

hola como estan tengo este query

```
SELECT 
    nom_emp,
    ISNULL (LENTES,0)[LENTE],
    Fecha_Gestion,
    ISNULL (AYUDA_ODONTOLOGICA,0)[AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA],
    Fecha_Gestion
FROM 
    (SELECT me.nom_emp,Fecha_Gestion,TB.Tipo_Benef,Monto
       FROM Tabla_Principal AS tp INNER JOIN Mes AS m ON M.id=TP.mes
    INNER JOIN Tipo_Beneficio AS tb ON TB.Id=TP.Tipo_Benef
    INNER JOIN Maestro_Empl AS me ON me.No_emp = tp.No_emp
    ) AS  TablaDatos
PIVOT 
    (
        SUM (Monto)
        FOR Tipo_Benef IN (LENTES,AYUDA_ODONTOLOGICA)
    )AS PivotTable
GO
```

como resultado me arroja[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta es por que la columna AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA me pone 0 ya que tiene datos

queria saber si me pueden ayudar o decir si estoy haciendo mal el PIVOT

estos son los datos que tengo en la tabla[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Norma, bienvenida. Puedes editar la pregunta para quitar las mayusculas? Y tambien sustituir la foto del codigo por Texto (para formatear el codigo lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl+k` o el icono `{}`). Gracias y un saludo

Comment: se pone feo el codigo por eso deje imagen

Comment: Por eso te digo: para formatear el codigo lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl+k` o el icono `{}`. Pero si no te sale ya lo hago yo por ti cuando lo pongas en texto

Comment: Para entender el resultado de tu query, necesitamos entender los datos que tienes en las tablas que participan en la consulta. En otras palabras, lo que se necesita es un [mcve]. El sitio http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler es muy útil para esto.

Comment: ¿Estas segura que tiene datos? Porque te esta colocando el cero cuando el valor es nulo.

Comment: si ahi puse en la ultima imagen los datos que contiene la tabla

Answer (score 10):

El comando `PIVOT` necesita que uses exactamente el valor que quieres "pivotear", en el `FOR`. Si revisas bien tus datos, puedes ver que el valor `AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA` tiene un espacio, no está escrito como `AYUDA_ODONTOLOGICA`. Por lo tanto, debes usar ese valor en tu `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT 
    nom_emp,
    ISNULL (LENTES,0)[LENTE],
    Fecha_Gestion,
    ISNULL ([AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA],0)[AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA],
    Fecha_Gestion
FROM 
    (SELECT me.nom_emp,Fecha_Gestion,TB.Tipo_Benef,Monto
       FROM Tabla_Principal AS tp INNER JOIN Mes AS m ON M.id=TP.mes
    INNER JOIN Tipo_Beneficio AS tb ON TB.Id=TP.Tipo_Benef
    INNER JOIN Maestro_Empl AS me ON me.No_emp = tp.No_emp
    ) AS  TablaDatos
PIVOT 
    (
        SUM (Monto)
        FOR Tipo_Benef IN (LENTES,[AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA])
    )AS PivotTable
;
```

Comment: me sigue arrojando cero

Comment: @norma Verifica espacios en blanco en el texto

Answer (score 2):

En tu tabla Tipo_Beneficio asegurate que el campo Tipo_Benef contenga valores AYUDA_ODONTOLOGICA, si estos no existen grabados en la tabla al remover `ISNULL` de la linea:

```
ISNULL(AYUDA_ODONTOLOGICA,0)[AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA]
```

Obtendras la columna con puros valor NULL

Ahora que si AYUDA_ODONTOLOGICA es AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA no uses el guion bajo y dejalo como:

```
FOR Tipo_Benef in (LENTES, [AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA])
```

**Nota: Los espacios en blanco en la celda al principio y al final se deben considerar ej:**

```
FOR Tipo_Benef in (LENTES, [AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA ]) --Espacio en blanco al final
```

Comment: hHAHA lamak te ha ninja'd por 7 seg! (buena vista igualmente)

Comment: Si me di cuenta que entre respuetas fueron 6 segundos de diferencia, igual ambas son la misma conclusion

Comment: ya verifique pero me sigue arrojando 0

Comment: @norma Verifica que AYUDA ODONTOLOGICA no contenga espacios al final o al principio en la celda, si estos estan presentes hay que agregarlos a la consulta de la tabla pivote o quitarlos de las celdas que contengan

Comment: Gracias chicos eso era los espacios Dios los bendiga

Comment: De nada, Saludos

Comment: Una pregunta como seria si lo quiero hacer dinamico

Comment: @norma Tienes que transformar la query a sql dinamico, usualmente almacenada en un varchar y concatenando en la consulta las partes que quieras volver diinamicas y mandar llamar la consulta meidante exec o sp_executesql, Si necesitas algo mas especifico en cuanto a volverlo dinamico no lo haces saber